# How is this not a violation of CPT symmetry?

Tags: cpt-symmetry, cpt-violation

Imagine an electron and a positron, initially held stationary some distance apart at time $t=0$. There is an attractive force between them, so they will approach one another.

I am told that all the fundamental laws of physics are CPT-symmetric, so let's try that out.

First, a P-inversion. Reflect the universe in such a way that the two particles switch places.

Then, a C-inversion. The electron becomes a positron and vice-versa. In other words, we are back to where we started.

Now a T-inversion. Running the dynamical laws backwards in time, the attractive force becomes a repulsive one: **the particles move further apart** instead of approaching.

This is not CPT symmetry as I understand it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Two basic misunderstandings here: 1) under time reversal the *velocity* changes sign but not the acceleration or the force, which remains attractive, and 2) symmetry of the laws does not imply that a particular *situation* is symmetrical, only that the transformed situation (which may be different) is also a valid solution of the laws. Which it is - there is no reason electrons and positrons can't move apart.

Comment: "only that the transformed situation (which may be different) is also a valid solution of the laws" - does this mean the laws having the transformation applied as well? i came to a similar conclusion as the op but thinking about electron and a proton, in the proton's frame time reversal does nothing to it, but it makes the electron behave as a positive charge would if time were not reversed...

Comment: now, if i use a neutron instead and pretend there are no residual forces at play and consider gravity I get a similar situation - except that the trajectory is not reversed under a charge or parity reversal. now i believe that this disobeys the laws of gravitation unless the law is transformed as well (there are no repulsive forces without negative mass afaik, and unlike signs will repel) - but then this seems to be nearly trivial - it will take exceptional cases to break that symmetry then, surely - like the values involved not being regular old real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

CPT symmetry (described as a **dynamical symmetry**) means that a **dynamical evolution**$s=s(t)$ is mapped into **another possible dynamical evolution** $s'=s'(t)$ if you transform under CPT every single state $s'(t) := CPTs(-t)$ connected by the initial dynamical evolution (reversing also the chronological order due to the presence of $T$).

In other words, *$s'$ solves the  equations of motion if $s$ does.*

This is the case in the considered situation.

In $s'$ the particles moves further  apart  because you also changed the initial conditions: the particle attract each other, but the (new) initial relative velocity is positive. In fact it now decreases as $t$ increases...

In fact, we can think of $s$ as defined in $[0,T]$. At $t=0$ the particle have zero velocity (in the laboratory) and they reach a great velocity at $t=T$. During the motion, the velocity of the electron points towards the positron and *vice versa*.

The CPT reversed story $s'$ is instead defined over $[-T,0]$. The (swapped) particles have a great velocity at the initial instant $t=-T$. Differently from what happens along $s$, now the velocity of the electron *diverges* from the positrons and *vice versa*. Therefore the particles start their motion with divergent velocities though they attract each other. Due to this attractive force, the velocities  decrease and vanish at $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

While it is pointing out the reader into some general directions, the general nature of answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/70858/139287 is in my taste too much handwaving. My personal perspective on this problem is as follows:

First, let us describe **the particles move further apart** by a formula. We can do this as follows: Let $l(t)$ designate the (non-zero, non-directional) distance between the two particles at time $t$. Now define the formula $B(t_1,t_2) :\Leftrightarrow t_1 > t_2 \Rightarrow l(t_1) > l(t_2)$. If $\forall t_1, t_2: B(t_1,t_2)$, ie. if $B(t_1,t_2)$ holds for all times $t_1$ and $t_2$, then we will call this **particles move further apart**.

In the experimental scenario *before* the C, P, T transformation, this is the case.

Now let us do the C, P, T transformation. It has no effect on the definition of $l$ but it transforms $B(t_1,t_2)$ into $B(-t_1, -t_2)$. So after the transformation we are interested whether $-t_1 > -t_2 \Rightarrow l(-t_1) > l(-t_2)$ holds for all $t_1, t_2$. This is the case. So after the T transformation the **particles still move further apart**.

To see the latter claim formally, you might want to apply some laws of logic. To see it informally, let us have a look at an example.

Let us chose in the situation *before* the T transformation the values $t_1 = 1$ and $t_2 = 0$. The precondition of the implication holds, $1 > 0 $, and the conclusion also holds, $l(1) > l(0)$. We know this, as in the situation *before* the T transformation the particles are moving further apart.

Now let us have a look at the situation *after* the CPT transformation, where the CPT theorem tells us that the transformed property agin holds. Here, let us pick $t_1 = -1$ and $t_2 = 0$.  We obtain $1 > 0$ as precondition, which holds, and therefore also $l(1) > l(0)$.

The problem you fell victim of is, in my opinion, an incorrect application of the CPT theorem.

The same mistake has been made in https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4937, where the author argues that the CPT theorem produces repulsive gravitation between matter and anti-matter. In https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5117 the problem associated with this line of reasoning is explained in detail. I guess the situation here is similar in nature, although easier to grasp.

**Edit:** Corrected a wrong use of a symbol.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.